# Angular NaNmageDirective error

Tags: angularjs

I am using [angularjs-imageupload-directive](https://github.com/Mischi/angularjs-imageupload-directive) for upload image in base64 in my application.

This directive give me error as below.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-NaNmageDirective
    at Error (native)
    at http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:10395
    at http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:25331
    at Object.c [as get] (http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:24402)
    at http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:25405
    at c (http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:24402)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:24617)
    at http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:29463
    at f (http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:10732)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://www.example.com/min/admin-production.min.js:19:29430)
```

Anyone have solution for this.

Comment: Check whether, did you add imageupload dependency to your module.

Comment: @Hurix Yeah, i add the dependency to module.

Comment: Can you post your code here or plnkr link would be great

Comment: Have you added the JS file to the main HTML file of your application? As said, showing a live code snippet reproducing the issue would avoid us to do guess games...

Comment: @PhiLho I add the js file in html file too.

Comment: Have you visited the given URL? http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-NaNmageDirective Maybe it will give some useful hint to find out what is the problem. The name NaNmageDirective sound stranges, looks like a badly computed name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[angularjs-imageupload-directive](https://github.com/Mischi/angularjs-imageupload-directive)  use following.

```
angular.module('imageupload', [])
    .directive('image',  function($q) {...}
```

It is not work after uglify. For the param $q may be converted to another name such as a,b,c,f, etc by uglify compiler.

So i convert it to and it works perfectly.

```
angular.module('imageupload', [])
    .directive('image', ['$q', function($q) {...}]
```